# clarification about ads in ios app

Tags: ios, ads

Well, I have read a lot about ads in ios app. It seems there are a lot of providers. 
What I understand it seems that adMob is the biggest/most used. iAds is provided by Apple itself, but what I've heard it seems you can get less money for it and, especially, it seems it works bad/generates less money in specific countries (I read about Sweden market).

My real question is: You can integrate multiple ads-provider in your app, cant you?
Is it common for those that release ios-apps to have 2 or more ads-provider?

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit to how many ad providers you can use in your app, but it would probably make sense to stick to one because they usually have a minimum amount of money you must generate before you can remove the earned funds.
Apple iAd's is not as bad you say, they usually offer a standard commission of 7% which with the new introduction of app bundles(multiple apps purchased together) could earn you a nice sum.